# Knex migration does not create tables

Tags: knex.js

I've got some Knex migration scripts that look like this:

```
'use strict';
exports.up = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema
        .hasTable('user')
        .then(function (exists) {
            if (!exists) {
                knex
                    .schema
                    .createTable('user', function (table) {
                        table.increments('id').primary();
                        table.string('firstName');
                        table.string('lastName');
                        table.string('email');
                        table.string('password');
                        table.string('username');
                    })
                    .then(console.log('created user table'));
            }
        });
};
```

The first time I ran this script, it created a table, which was great, but then I noticed that the table was malformed (I had passed a wrong parameter.) So I manually deleted the created table from my database, along with the knex_migrations and knex_migrations_lock tables, and re-ran the migration command. Now, it tells me that all migrations have run, but I still don't see the table. What gives? Is there a piece of of config hiding somewhere that I need to delete?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

add "return".

```
'use strict';
exports.up = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema
        .hasTable('user')
        .then(function (exists) {
            if (!exists) {
              return knex // **** udpate
                    .schema
                    .createTable('user', function (table) {
                        table.increments('id').primary();
                        table.string('firstName');
                        table.string('lastName');
                        table.string('email');
                        table.string('password');
                        table.string('username');
                    })
                    .then(console.log('created user table'));
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Didn't realize I skipped that

Comment: This is great! Also using `await` for `knex.schema` instead of return is okay!

Comment: i am using Sqlite3, and it seems its not working in my part.

Comment: @Bob Here is code that works for me when using **knex** and node.js with a **async/await**: [https://gist.github.com/charliecalvert/b90cd09bff12c599754a1a3e68ff8769](https://gist.github.com/charliecalvert/b90cd09bff12c599754a1a3e68ff8769)